# Application Object "Out Of Range" Error Initializing Legacy VB6 COM-Addin for Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, vb6, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I'm attempting to ensure compatibility for an old VB6 COM-addin for Outlook 2013.  It's worked fine (more or less) for every version since 2002 but in testing 2013 I'm getting an odd error when I attempt to initialize.

As soon as I try to take ANY action on the Outlook Application object I blow up with a **"09 - Subscript Out Of Range"** error.  Even something as benign as casting the the olApp parameter I'm bringing into the class as a private var blows up.  The Application object isn't null, it's property rich and seemingly initialized.

```
Friend Sub InitHandler(olApp As Outlook.Application, strProgID As String)

On Error GoTo ErrorExit

'If Outlook is opened without main UI (i.e. 'mailto:' HTML link)
If Explorers.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

' BLOWS UP SO TRIED COMMENTING IT OUT AND ACCESSING PARAMETER DIRECTLY
'Set objOutlook = olApp

' ALSO BLOWS UP
Set objNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

...
```

Have there been any major architectural changes to the object model?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I needed to install the VB6 service pack 6 and cumulative rollout update.